# Printing A3 format map

Tags: qgis, printing

I have a question about printing A3 map from QGIS. I'm going to make A3 map of one country and nearby countries, digitalise borders etc. I want to save it to A3 format, but I have only A4 printer, that prints my map on one sheet of paper, not two, as I expected. If I use A3 printer, my map will print in proper size? I saved my map in PDF, if relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Simply install a printer that prints in file. Choose a big color printer from let's say HP that supports A3 and direct the output to file. Then select the printer from your print dialog and make the setting as usual for the paper format.... Done.

PS: I would look for a printer driver that supports PS

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose the printing format in "print manager" / composition as showed in the below picture (sorry for language setted on my regional version).

[image: composition]

Comment: And that's all? I did so, in PDF it looks ok, but my A4 printer doesn't print it correctly. I hope it will print OK when I go xero point with A3 or bigger printers.

Comment: Once you have printed a A3 pdf you have to print on the phisical printer with the proportion of 100% (not adapt to paper limits) an you will have your A3 paper